# SQL Join: Everything in the LEFT table that is NOT IN the RIGHT Table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables, "Affiliates" and "ControlPanels".

ControlPanels has a field (CP_AffiliateID) that maps to Affiliates (A_ID).

I want to select all records from Affiliates that DO NOT have a match in CP_AffiliateID.

The fields A_ID is a Primary Key so I'm not worried about matching NULL.

What would that join look like?

Comment: `Affiliates LEFT OUTER JOIN ControlPanels ON A_id = cp_affiliateID WHERE ControlPanels.CP_AffiliateID IS NULL` OR you could do `FROM Affiliates aff WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ControlPanels cp WHERE cp.cp_affiliate_id = aff.a_id)`

Comment: @JNevill, THANKS! I don't think it's a dup b/c I'm not concerned with matching on NULL, as A_ID is a Primary Key. HTH.

Comment: @nbardach look more closely at the duplicate and how it relates to your question.  Looking for NULL in the `CP_AffiliateID` is absolutely a correct way to do this.  It matters not that `A_ID` is a Primary Key.

Comment: @Tab Aleman, actually, it's not that I want all records from Affiliates where CP_AffiliateID IS NULL. It's just that if there's is '5' in CP_AffiliateID, I don't want to include the record from Affiliates where A_ID = '5';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try **NOT IN**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   affiliates 
WHERE  affiliates.a_id NOT IN (SELECT cp_affiliateid 
                                  FROM   controlpanels)
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution. Thanks, Hardik!

Comment: Welcome @nbardach :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a join for this and can just use `!= ALL (subquery)`.

```
SELECT * FROM Affiliates A 
WHERE a.A_ID != ALL (SELECT C.CP_AffiliateID FROM ControlPanels C)
```

Comment: This is valid for SQL Server???  i've never heard of this syntax.

Comment: Since SQL Server 2008. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yeah, I very, very rarely see anyone use ALL, SOME, ANY, or even !=  http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLAllSome.aspx

Comment: Looks like it does the same thing as NOT IN.

Comment: Interesting syntax. I've never used ALL before.